# How to ensure execution of if statement despite other ongoing tasks - finch robot

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been tasked with creating a program which will lead a finch robot to move around somewhat randomly for the allotted amount of time, while counting the number of objects that it detects during the movement and returning this amount to then be displayed.

I can get the robot to move randomly, and I can get it to count objects that it detects - but not at the same time.

main:

```
    int millsec = 5000;
    int obstacleOccur = finchRandom(millsec);
    System.out.println(obstacleOccur);
```

method:

```
static public int finchRandom(int x)
{
    Finch myf = new Finch();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int obs = 0;
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis()+x;

    while(time - System.currentTimeMillis() > 0)
    {
        if (myf.isObstacle())
        {
            obs++; //this counts the obstacles
            System.out.println("Obstacle");
        }   //below activates the wheels to move randomly,
            //the function is setWheelVelocities(leftWheel,rightWheel,duration)
            myf.setWheelVelocities(rand.nextInt(150)-75,rand.nextInt(150)-75,rand.nextInt(x/2));        
    }
    return obs; //returns the count of obstacles
}
```

I believe it is because the if statement and incrementation for counting obstacles can't be ran while the finch robot is moving around. Are there any ways around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is multithreaded programming, your job is to figure out how to use THread or Runnable or a lambda expression to do so.  Because any given thread can only do one thing at a time, and you need to be doing at least two things at a time.